# how to change TextFormField hint label background color in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface

How to change TextFormField hint label background color in flutter?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`backgroundColor`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle/backgroundColor.html) propetry of `TextStyle` to change the background color of `labelText` or `hintText`:

```dart
TextFormField(
  decoration: const InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Hint Text',
    labelText: 'Label Text',
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red, // Change background color for hint text
    ),
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue, // Change background color for label text
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: applies this solution but does not look properly.https://ibb.co/qCy30Xq

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the `hintStyle` of `InputDecoration`